# count two arraylist A and B and count values in A which are less than each num of B

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist

Given two arraylist A and B, A={3,4,5] and B=[4,7], count how many numbers in A are less or equal than each element in B. In this case B.get(0)=4 is has 2 values less or equal in A,i.e 3 and 4, similarly 7 has 3 values. So the function should return list=[2,3].
I have solved this question using two for loops, which works for smaller inputs ,however as the size grows the performance is degraded.

```
import java.util.*;
public class checkDiff{
public static void check(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B) {
    List<Integer> result=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<B.size();i++){
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<A.size();j++){
            if(A.get(j)<=B.get(i)){
                 count++;
            }           
        }
    result.add(i,count);
    }
   for(int x:result){
    System.out.println(x);
   }

}

 public static void main(String []args){
     List<Integer> A=new ArrayList<Integer>();
     List<Integer> B=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    A.add(3);
    A.add(4);
    A.add(7);
    B.add(4);
    B.add(7);
    check(A,B);
    
 }
 }
```

Is there any way to optimize this code.Please help.

Comment: If you were to sort each array, you can make one traversal across both in parallel, since you will know if ```B.get(0)``` has 2 lower numbers (for instance), ```B.get(1)``` has _at least_ the same amount (since ```B.get(1)``` > ```B.get(0)```) and can skip the indices you already checked in ```A```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you are taking an array which is not sorted value wise. Hence you will have to check all the possible combinations and you cannot make this process faster unless and until you use a sorted list or use data structure like binary search tree.